# Travis CI - Run deploy step (PyPI) as sudo?

Tags: python, travis-ci, pypi

I have a Python project that uses tox. Some unit tests require sudo, so .travis.yml has

```
script:
- sudo tox
```

However, this leaves the egg-info file and others owned by root. So when Travis runs the deploy step (as user), it gives the following output:

```
Deploying application
running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to myproject.egg-info/requires.txt
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'myproject.egg-info/requires.txt'
ValueError: Cannot find file (or expand pattern): 'dist/*'
```

How can I run the deploy step as root, or otherwise get around this issue?

Comment: Try `sudo -E` or `-H` or both

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of whether some smartness can be applied with `tox` itself, but you could start your `deploy` stage with a script along the following lines:

```
- sudo chown --changes --recursive $(whoami):$(id --group $(whoami)) .
```

This sets all the files in the current directory to the current user, and the main group of the current user.